# Pugh problem 1.3: quantified statements

Tags: quantifiers

> Recast the following English sentences in mathematics, using correct mathematical grammar. Preserve their meaning.
>
> a) $2$ is the smallest prime number.
>
> b) The area of any bounded plane region is bisected by some line parallel to the $x$-axis.
>
> c) "All that glitters is not gold."

After some help in the comments, I have a revised attempt.

a) Define the predicate $P(n)$ for $n$ is a prime number. Then:
$$P(2) \wedge \forall p, \; P(p) \implies p \geq 2.$$
b) I am still unsure on how to write part (b).

c) Define the predicate:

Glitter($x$): $x$ glitters
Gold($x$): $x$ is gold

The quantification:
$$\forall x, \; \text{Glitter}(x) \implies \neg \text{Gold}(x).$$
The problem with (c) is that the universe of discourse is not specified, so when I say "for each $x$," it is not clear what I am referring to.

Comment: $\exists x=2$ is not syntactically correct.

Comment: The existential quantifier is not needed, using the *term* $2$. "2  is the smallest prime number" can be unwinded into: "2 is prime **and** every prime is greater-or-equal to it". $\text P(2) \land \forall p (\text P(p) \to p \ge 2)$.

Comment: For c) Yes; you have to use two predicates: Glitter(x) and Gold(x).

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I've revised my answer with another attempt. In (c) in particular, I am not sure what the domain of discourse is, so ir doesn't seem that we have defined $x$ in any way.

Comment: Re your new c): "All that glitters is not gold" is Ok. "All" means **all**, thus the domain is "everything".